# PDF dataextraction failing on some of the pdf

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, data-extraction, pdftotext

For one of my assignment, I am supposed to extract data from the pdf file then save then into a text file which will be used later to create an NLP model for document extraction
I had used pdftotext library to extract each page of the given pdf file.
The problem with the approach is for some of the files I am getting byte/hexa output like below which can't be read by a human -
[image: Output -]

Please guide me on how can I declare the above-extracted output as not extractable data from the pdf file.

Code used for data extraction -
For pdftotext -

```
import pdftotext
import os
import warnings


def writeTxt(data):
  file1 = open("output.txt","w")
  file1.write(data) 


def extract_information(file):
  # Load your PDF
  with open(file, "rb") as f:
      pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

  # How many pages?
  print("Page Length : ",len(pdf))

  # Iterate over all the pages
  for page in pdf:
      writeTxt(page)
      print(page)
```

Need help in classifying above mentioned output as non extractable i.e classifying those pages which has only byte/hexa values.

Comment: Please format your question and explain better your purpose.

Comment: @anakin87 I have re-formatted the question. Please guide. Need help urgently.